# jQuery jScrollPane: how to disable?

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

I need a command that would disable jQuery jScrollPane when a certain condition is met.

Couldn't find it anywhere online, hope someone on StackOverflow knows the solution.

I would appreciate your sharing it with me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var a = false;
var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({/*params*/});

if(a !== true)
{
    api.destroy();
}
```

[Documentation on destroy();](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/destroy.html)

Comment: Hey Webguy! Thanks for being ready to help. jScrollPaneRemove(); doesn't work: the scrollbar stays. You wouldn't happen to know any other command that would do the trick? Or maybe you could suggest a statement that disables the mousewheel - in that case I would hide the scrollbar and diable the mousewheel. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: Thank you. This is perfect. You saved me a great deal of time, and I learned something useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = false;
var api = $('.scroll-pane').data('jsp');

if(a !== true)
{
    api.destroy();
}
```

To update @AlienWebguy 's answer, in 2015 this is the way to destroy jScrollPane